# Has anyone published a formula for the volume of the intersection of two balls

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, maple

Math people:

I have Googled this question and searched Math Stack Exchange, and not found an answer.  Given $r_1, r_0, t >0$, $r_0 \leq r_1$ I have found a formula for the volume of the intersection of two three-dimensional balls with radii $r_0$ and $r_1$ and centers separated by $t$.  It is obvious what it is if $t \leq r_1 - r_0$ or $t \geq r_1 + r_0$.  For $r_1 -r_0 \leq t \leq r_1 + r_0$, it is polynomial (cubic) in $r_0$ and $r_1$ and rational in $t$, with powers of $t$ going from $t^{-1}$ to $t^3$, if I remember correctly.  I found it using Calc 3 techniques and some help from Maple to simplify some nasty expressions.

Someone has to have done this before.  Has anyone ever seen a formula for this?  This is part of a research project and I don't want to take credit for it if someone has done it before.

Stefan (STack Exchange FAN)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mathworld has the formula (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sphere-SphereIntersection.html), and cites Kern and Bland 1948, but I haven't checked if the book actually contains the formula.

Several sources have the formula for the volume of a spherical cap (from which you can get the volume of the spherical intersection), for instance the Handbook of Mathematics and Computational Science.

In any case, in your position I would treat the volume of intersection as "well known."

Comment: I think I already entered this comment, but I don't see it now... I spent hours deriving this formula, when I could have been doing something else!

Answer (score 3):

The region you ask about is the union of two [spherical caps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap).  The volume of intersection of two balls, even of different radii, can be worked out from the sum of those two volumes.

That is, the bounding spheres intersect in a circle (if at all, the case of one sphere nested in another being trivial), and the plane that circle lies in cuts off a spherical cap from each ball.  Add their volumes and you have the volume of intersection.

The higher-dimensional cases are discussed in [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162250/how-to-compute-the-volume-of-intersection-between-two-hyperspheres).