# a question on the volume of a set

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

Can anybody give me a hint on this?
Let $v\in \mathbb{R}^n,\quad r,R,C$ positive constants .
We would like to calculate the volume of the set $$A=\{w\in \mathbb{R}^n : r\leq |w| \leq R, |w-v/2|\leq C \}$$
It seems like the intersection of an annulus and a ball (both in the n-dimensional sense) but i can't write down an integral properly.

Comment: You need to figure out the volume of intersection between two hypersphere and substract....
$$\mu(A) = \mu\left((\bar{B}_R(0) \setminus B_r(0))\cap \bar{B}_C(\frac{v}{2})\right)
= \mu\left(\bar{B}_R(0) \cap \bar{B}_C(\frac{v}{2})\right)
 -\mu\left(B_r(0) \cap \bar{B}_C(\frac{v}{2})\right)
$$

Comment: To compute the volume of intersection between two hypershere, see answer of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162250/how-to-compute-the-volume-of-intersection-between-two-hyperspheres) and the wiki entry on [hyperspherical cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap#Hyperspherical_cap).